# IMediaSample Time and MediaTime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow

What is the primary difference between SetTime and SetMediaTime?

Right now in my directshow livesource I calculate the time it like this

```
REFERENCE_TIME rtStart = m_rtLastSampleTime;
m_rtLastSampleTime += pVih->AvgTimePerFrame;
pms->SetTime(&rtStart, &m_rtLastSampleTime);
pms->SetSyncPoint(TRUE);
pms->SetDiscontinuity(rtStart <= 1);
```

This doesn't work with some encoders.
I've noticed that source that do work with these encoders set mediatime and they seem to jump up.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Optionally, the filter can also specify a media time for the sample. In a video stream, media time represents the frame number. In an audio stream, media time represents the sample number in the packet. For example, if each packet contains one second of 44.1 kilohertz (kHz) audio, the first packet has a media start time of zero and a media stop time of 44100. In a seekable stream, the media time is always relative to the start time of the stream. For example, suppose you seek to 2 seconds from the start of a 15-fps video stream. The first media sample after the seek has a time stamp of zero but a media time of 30.
>
> Renderer and mux filters can use the media time to determine whether frames or samples have been dropped, by checking for gaps. However, filters are not required to set the media time. To set the media time on a sample, call the IMediaSample::SetMediaTime method.

I don't think it is actually used anywhere. `SetTime`, on the contrary, is important.